# How to improve performance of an ALTER TABLE? [dropping collation]

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I've got a 'huge' table with 750k records. I need to alter some columns of this table. I have the following statements:

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [MyFirstField]  NTEXT          NULL
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [MySecondField] NVARCHAR (50)  NULL
```

- **MyFirstField** is changed from `NTEXT COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL`
- **MySecondField** is changed from `NVARCHAR (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL`

It takes quite some time to convert all the records. Any ideas how to spead up this process?

Comment: A table with 750k records is very far from being huge.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I know :-) that's why I'm surprised it takes this long :-)

Comment: Slightly off topic, but use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `NTEXT`, NTEXT will eventually be removed from SQL-Server. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx

Comment: Will be slower but you could create the new table and then insert into it X records at a time.  Again would talk longer but you could insert 100 and at least get a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't speed this up.

The text values for each and every column need to be converted from the selected collation to the default one. This takes time.

Comment: No way to prevent locks and stuff like that? Nothing need to be logged (I think).

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker - This is not the kind of change I would make without logging.